# Accessing yielded variable only once

Tags: python, yield

So we have a function like this:

```
def infinite_sequence():
  num = 0
  while True:
    yield num
    time.sleep(1)
    num += 1
```

The bellow code:

```
    for num in infinite_sequence():
      print(num)
```

will result in printing this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Now imagine that *infinite_sequence()* runs in the background, and I need to print only actual *num* variable.

Ex: after a minute of running *infinite_sequence()* the result should be *60*

How do I do this?

Comment: You only want to print the last value?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. If you want to know how many seconds have passed since "action X", just keep track of it with a timestamp. You could even wrap it in a class and then use the same instance to query "seconds since action X".

Comment: @Aran-Fey exactly, yes

Comment: There is no "last" value; how exactly are you "stopping" `infinite_sequence`?

Comment: @chepner Im not stopping it, that's the hard thing. New value is generated every 1sec and I need to access last one generated

Comment: You need a separate thread of execution that updates a shared variable you can query independently.

Comment: There is no "last" value generated. The values are only generated when you ask for them. They're not generated ahead of time so there's no "current" value, and they're not stored anywhere such that you can ask for a previously generated value. It definitely sounds like an XY problem. You have problem X and you're asking about attempted solution Y (a generator that sleeps). Could you tell us about problem X instead?

Comment: why not use a global variable to increase it, and yield that value, then you need to import your infinty function on top  of your module

Comment: `runs in background` doesn't make sense. Are you iterating on this sequence via `for` or `next`? If yes, there are simpler ways to do want you want. If no, we need some explanation about your code.

Answer (score 1):

Generators can’t “run” (in the background or otherwise) by themselves.  But if a thread is iterating over it (with negligible processing delay), it could also store that value somewhere:

```
def stash(it,box):
  for x in it:
    box[0]=x
    # more fast operations on x…

# elsewhere
box=[None]
th=threading.Thread(target=stash,args=(infinite_sequence(),box))
th.start()
while …:
  latest=box[0]
  # operate on latest
```

With CPython, at least, the unsynchronized access to the list element is safe, although of course it may be out of date before you use it.